# NET MAUI CommunityToolkit.MVVM throws error on email validation attribute

Tags: c#, data-annotations, maui-community-toolkit, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have wrote an email validation attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EmailAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public EmailAttribute() : base(@"[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}")
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid email address";
    }
}
```

When the validation has been called, the validator runs ok, and when exits throws an error:

**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'**

I tried changing the validator implementation, and for every it throws me the same error message.
If I remove the email validation attribute from the object's property everything works. If I add some new random validation attribute it works.

Here is my model:

```
public partial class LoginModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string email = string.Empty;
    private string password = string.Empty;


    [Required]
    [MinLength(5)]
    [Email]
    public string Email
    {
        get => this.email;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.email, value, true);
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[Email]");
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [MinLength(8)]
    public string Password
    {
        get => this.password;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.password, value, true);
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorDictionary[Password]");
        }
    }
}
```

thnx

Answer (score -1):

I get the same error failure when the `ValidationResult` is not a success and I return `ValidationResult` error message of type string.

If the `validationResult` is `ValidationResult.Success` then it works and even changes the control to a different color if I wish. Therefore it is the xaml view receiving an incompatible value in the binding expecting bool but gets a string

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33830659)

Comment: Ive tried to modify it to be helpful information

Comment: Even helpful or additional information is not an answer if it doesn't attempt to solve the problem. Your answer should have been a comment, but you cannot post comments yet due to a lack of reputation, which means you need to either provide a working solution or wait until you've earned enough reputation to write comments. I've made the same mistake before, but those are the rules.