# Validation with ObservableValidator error on GetErrors() .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, validation, maui

When using ObservableValidator class with ValidationAttribute an error occurs in the ValidationStatus block on the GetErrors() line.

The error is **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'** The underlying error is **"Sequence has no Elements".**

When there are no errors and ValidationStatus is success false is returned and behaviour is normal, however when a validation error occurs the crash occurs

Here is the code;

ViewModelBase inherits ObservableValidator

```
    public partial class PartAResultList : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string PartAResultId { get; set; }

        [ObservableProperty]
         int outletIndex;

        private double? staticPressResult;

        [GreaterThan(nameof(StaticPressSpec))]
        public double? StaticPressResult
        {
            get => this.staticPressResult;
            set
            {
                ClearErrors();
                SetProperty(ref this.staticPressResult, value, true);
                ValidateAllProperties();
                OnPropertyChanged("Item[StaticPressResult]");
            }
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        public double? staticPressSpec;


        [IndexerName("Item")]
        public ValidationStatus this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {

                var errors = this.GetErrors()
                                 .ToDictionary(k => k.MemberNames.First(), v => v.ErrorMessage) ?? new Dictionary<string, string?>();

                var hasErrors = errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var error);
                return new ValidationStatus(hasErrors, error ?? string.Empty);
            }
        }

    }
```

```
    public class ValidationStatus : ObservableObject
    {
        private bool hasError;
        private string error;

        public bool HasError
        {
            get => this.hasError;
            set => SetProperty(ref this.hasError, value);
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get => this.error;
            set => SetProperty(ref this.error, value);
        }

        public ValidationStatus()
        {
        }

        public ValidationStatus(bool hasError, string error)
        {
            this.hasError = hasError;
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

```
    public sealed class GreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public GreaterThanAttribute(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyName = propertyName;
        }

        public string PropertyName { get; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            object
                instance = validationContext.ObjectInstance,
                otherValue = instance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance);

            if (((IComparable)value).CompareTo(otherValue) > 0)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

            return new("out of specification");
        }
    }
```

```
<Entry
Text="{Binding StaticPressResult}"
                                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                            <Entry.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry"
                                                         Binding="{Binding [StaticPressResult].HasError}"
                                                         Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Entry.Triggers>
</Entry>
```

I have copied this code from another source and hitting my limit of c# expertise to debug it. THis is from [NET MAUI CommunityToolkit.MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75238719/net-maui-communitytoolkit-mvvm-throws-error-on-email-validation-attribute). K.MemberNames.First() value is {String[0]} but cannot evaluate children. The "K" variable shows the error message "out of specification" from the GReaterThanAttribute. Im assuming the "Sequence has no Elements" is like passing an invalid value to the xaml binding which causes the **'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**

Comment: I'd suggest breaking that line up into multiple statements and figuring out which one is actually causing the issue, then look at the values of the objects to determine why

Comment: @Jason well thank you for that. I broke it down then that also helped me to rewrite it so I got it to work by changing the code. I suspect now the problem could be the "K.MemberNames.First() value is {String[0]}" code. My code though isnt as good as original so will still and see whats wrong.

Comment: If possible, could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT here is a working example [link](https://github.com/ideas2appsaustralia/MauiValidation)

Comment: @scott Thanks for the response,I would look into it and give you an update on it.

Comment: Like you said,`"Sequence has no Elements"` indicating that you are passing an invalid value to the xaml binding, you need pass a double number to it.